# Raspberry Pi 5 OS 32bit or 64bit and AnyDesk

Tags: raspberry-pi

Complletely new to Raspberry OS, I have used the Raspberry imager to write the OS to a SIM card. When making my selection in the imager I selected the device Raspberry Pi 5, the operating system as 32bit and the storage to the SIM card.

I had no problems during the write to the SIM and it completed displaying a banner the the 32bit OS had been written to the SIM card,

After booting the Raspberry Pi 5 I took a look using Terminal at what version the OS was: command line: sudo uname -m. The response was "aarch64". Because I thought I had made a mistake when selecting the OS type in the imager I perform the process again. Once completed I put the SIM back in the Raspberry and ran the same command in terminal with the same result, "aarch64".

The reason I chose the 32bit version was I need to run AnyDesk and it only runs on the 32bit OS.

My question is why did the imager write the 64bit OS to the SIM card and not the 32bit version.

Has anyone had this problem?